# how to encrypt an 2 attributes with the same iv and salt in attr_encrypted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

I have 2 attributes say `user_name` and `password`. I want to encrypt both using `attr_encrypted` using the `per_attribute_iv_and_salt` mode where I store the `iv` and `salt` in the database. I dont want to use a separate `iv` and `salt` for each attribute. Is there a mode with just one `Iv` and `Salt` to encrypt both?